# Xamarin forms youtube subscription button?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, youtube-data-api

I am using YouTube DataAPI v3 to make subscription button for YouTube channels

and I made the user to make sign-in first with google account and I got success at that Code

```
void login()
{
    clientId = null;
    redirectUri = null;

    switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
    {
        case Device.iOS:
            clientId = AppConstant.Constants.iOSClientId;
            redirectUri = AppConstant.Constants.iOSRedirectUrl;
            break;

        case Device.Android:
            clientId = AppConstant.Constants.AndroidClientId;
            redirectUri = AppConstant.Constants.AndroidRedirectUrl;
            break;
    }

    account = store.FindAccountsForService(AppConstant.Constants.AppName).FirstOrDefault();

    var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(
        clientId,
        null,
        AppConstant.Constants.Scope,
        new Uri(AppConstant.Constants.AuthorizeUrl),
        new Uri(redirectUri),
        new Uri(AppConstant.Constants.AccessTokenUrl),
        null,
        true);

    authenticator.Completed += OnAuthCompleted;
    authenticator.Error += OnAuthError;
    AuthenticationState.Authenticator = authenticator;
    var presenter = new Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.OAuthLoginPresenter();
    presenter.Login(authenticator);
}

async void OnAuthCompleted(object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var authenticator = sender as OAuth2Authenticator;
    if (authenticator != null)
    {
        authenticator.Completed -= OnAuthCompleted;
        authenticator.Error -= OnAuthError;
    }

    User user = null;
    if (e.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        string duration = e.Account.Properties["expires_in"];
        // If the user is authenticated, request their basic user data from Google
        // UserInfoUrl = https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo
        var request = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri(AppConstant.Constants.UserInfoUrl), null, e.Account);
        var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        if (response != null)
        {
            // Deserialize the data and store it in the account store
            // The users email address will be used to identify data in SimpleDB
            tok = e.Account.Properties["access_token"];
            string userJson = await response.GetResponseTextAsync();
            user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(userJson);
        }

        if (user != null)
        {
            //App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyDashBoardPage());

        }
        await store.SaveAsync(account = e.Account, AppConstant.Constants.AppName);
        await DisplayAlert("Email address", user.Email, "OK");
        PostRequest("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&key=myapi");
    }
}
```

I got the google user information but that's not my problem, the issue is
to can success subscribe channels I have to make the user to login-in and then he can subscribe at the channel id, but I don't know what is the way to make it? that the codes I am using to make subscribe and the errors are:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

that's my code

```
async void PostRequest(string URL)
{

    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

    var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {

        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("snippet", ""),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resourceId", ""),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("channelId", "id")
    });

    var response = await client.PostAsync(URL, formContent);
    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Events result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Events>(json);
}
```

and when I made this code

```
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",tok);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {

        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("snippet", ""),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resourceId", ""),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("channelId", "ID")
    });

    var response2 = await client.PostAsync(URL, formContent);
    var json = await response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Events result2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Events>(json);
```

I got that error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Insufficient Permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Emad. Please explain the code and what you try to do in more lines so people can help you, Your question is confusing and please explain what you tried to do so people can better help you.

Comment: @ItsRaptorman thanks for your reply i will update my question

Comment: Welcome. My best wishes.